# Force Unity Dash application to launch with a custom option

Tags: unity

I would like to make a program in the Unity Dash to launch with a custom option, as for example in the terminal it would be

> xyz --reconfig

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

What you want to do is edit the launcher, or desktop, file. Open up terminal and type:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/(NAME OF YOUR PROGRAM).desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Then, run:

```
 gedit ~/.local/share/applications/(NAME OF YOUR PROGRAM).desktop
```

The document at the top should say "Exec" somewhere. Add whatever you want to after the program name there, save, and either logout or run `unity --replace`.

Edit:

The command `cp /usr/share/appications/(NAME OF YOUR PROGRAM).desktop ~/.local/share/applications/` copies the original file over to a folder that is for only one user. If you want to make it so that a launcher is changed across all users, run `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/(NAME OF YOUR PROGRAM).desktop` but make sure you back up the original first.